# Get all customer that bought 2 product

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following 'simple' dataset

```
Customer  product    qty

A           p1        1
A           p2        1
B           p1        1
B           p3        1
C           p1        1
D           p2        1
D           p1        1
```

I need to get all customer that bought BOTH p1 and p2 , so the result will be A and D.
How to do in mysql without pivoting ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm repeating Alma's answer because I think the commentary attached to that answer introduces unnecessary confusion which the answer itself does not adequately address.

```
SELECT customer
     , COUNT(DISTINCT product) ttl -- DISTINCT is only necessary if (customer,product) is NOT unique
  FROM t
 WHERE product IN ('p1', 'p2')
 GROUP 
    BY customer
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- where 2 is equal to the number of items in IN();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want *exact* match (i.e. strictly `p1`, `p2` and nothing else), then:

```
SELECT
  Customer,
  COUNT(DISTINCT product) AS products_count
FROM 
  t
WHERE
  product IN ('p1', 'p2')
GROUP BY
  Customer
HAVING
  -- >=2 in case if you'll want to include other products, not only p1 and p2
  -- but p1 and p2 must present. Note, that IN() must be modified also
  products_count=2
```

upd. (*This gone after editing*)
with "at least" you'll need to add some extra-conditions to `IN` (or values into it) - that's because current `WHERE` condition will leave only `p1` and `p2` .

Comment: Indeed (modifying, not able to edit now). That's because we need to group products independent of how many times they were bought. However, group is Customer->product, thus, grouping was changed in order to satisfy common case

Comment: It's hard to post in two forms in same times (well, first was query window). So apologies. For customers who _only_ bought - no `JOIN` needed since `COUNT(DISTINCT)` with `IN (p1, p2)` will return `2` _only_ in case if that customer bought p1 and p2

Comment: It isn't wrong. We're grouping by Customer and counting products - with distinct clause. That means only for those who bought _exactly_ p1 and p2 it will be `2`. But for those, who bought, for example, p1, p2 and p10 - it will be `3`. Thus, `=2` stands for exact match and `>=2` for "at least" match

Comment: And that's why I've posted about `IN` (so it will be needed to add values there or add some extra-condition via `OR`)

Comment: //oops. You're right. That comment has gone in edit, accidentally I think. Added that back again, thx